# call parent dispatch before child dispatch django

Tags: django

I have a mixin which beside other things simplifies call of `request.user` object.

```
class MyMixin(LoginRequiredMixin, View):

    ...
    leader = False
    employee = False

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        self.leader = request.user.is_leader()
        self.employee = request.user.is_employee()

        return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    ...
```

And I have a heir of `DetailView` which has it's own dispatch method.

```
class MyDetailView(MyMixin, DetailView):

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        if not self.leader:
            raise PermissionDenied

        return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

But as you could've told it ain't working. Is there a way to elegantly call parent `dispatch` method from it's heir?

Answer (score 0):

You could make your attributes into properties so that the order of execution does not matter. Using [`cached_property`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/utils/#module-django.utils.functional) will mean that the property is only evaluated once for each request

```
from django.utils.functional import cached_property

class MyMixin(LoginRequiredMixin, View):

    @cached_property
    def leader(self):
        return self.request.user.is_leader()

    @cached_property
    def employee(self):
        return self.request.user.is_employee()
```